# Issues with the CSS z-index

Tags: css, css-position, z-index

I have an issue with the z-index. Can anyone check this code, please?
CSS:

```
#apps_button {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin-left:16px;
    margin-top:16px;
    margin-right:16px;
    z-index:10;
}

#apps_box {
    display:none;
    background-color:#3F51B5;
    height:50vh;
    width:50vh;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:10;
    box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.24),0 4px 28px rgba(0,0,0,.48);
}

#apps_button:hover ~ #apps_box {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    display:block;
    z-index:10;
}

#apps_box:hover {
    display:block;
}
```

HTML (just a part):

```
            <span>
                <img src="img/apps.svg" id="apps_button">
                <div id="apps_box">
                    Apps
                </div>
            </span>
        </span>
    </header>
    <div id="body_content">
        <?php include("contents/Home/index.html"); ?>               
    </div>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

The whole code is uploaded on here:
https://www.skools.cu.ma/home.php
When I hover over #apps_button, the #apps_box is being displayed. But under the #body_content.
If you visit the code on my website, then please visit it on mobile phones because it's made for only mobile devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the z-index negative on #body_content

```
    #body_content {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 80%;
    width: 86%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 16%;
    left: 7%;
    right: 7%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.24), 0 4px 28px rgba(0,0,0,.48);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    z-index: -10;
}
```

Comment: The navigation menu, which I used in that page, is working properly. I tried adding it's style into #apps_box. But the result is still negative.

Comment: sorry! Now it is really working. I had a little problem with cashe files. Now, everything is working perfectly.

Comment: Done! Is it possible to accept two answers for same question?

Comment: I thought if I accept the other person's answer too, then he could also get more reps.

Comment: Do you want reps?

Comment: Up-voted Two of your questions. One about a percentage calculator and the other one is something like "manually adding...."

Comment: don't have enough time to read those questions. So, I just up-voted 'em.

Comment: I'm open for everybody. My WhatsApp number is 8848276151

Answer (score 1):

I opened your link and its working fine, the content is showing above body and header content.

If you figured it out, pls update. Thank You

Comment: Oh sorry! Now it is really working. I had a little problem with cashe files. Now, everything is working perfectly. Mr.Chandan's answer maybe right.